# how to start one activity from another

Tags: android

I have run one activity from main. I want If button is pressed, kill this user interface and activate other user interface to do other jobs.Mainly ;

```
   in onClick ( view temp)  


       switch( temp . getId () ) { 
            case R.id.button_validate:
                   // raise other vindow after killing current one
```

My other activity class name is renderman. How can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button_validate:
            Intent i=new Intent(this,renderman.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
           //use multiple case(for multiple button) like this if you need
        case R.id.exit_button:
            finish();  //to kill current one
    }
}
```

And add these lines in AndroidManifest.xml..

```
<activity 
    android:name=".renderman">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, renderman.class));
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you want to start the activity put the code `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Renderman.class))`

Also in your manifest put the following

```
    <activity 
        android:name=".Renderman"
        >
    </activity>
</application>
```

You should (but dont have to)capitalise the first letter of your class names

If you want to literally 'kill' your old activity, after you start the new activity with the code above out `finish()`

To stop the problem that you are having, do the following

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
//nothing, because you do not want anything to happen when you press back
}
```

Comment: You have missed `finish();` as he suggests "killing current one"

Comment: The problem is whenever I press back button on the Android emulator, first screen will be called( from which I have call other user interface). I do not want to see the first screen after the other activities are callef.How can I manage? If still unclear pleasr say because english is not my native language.